# No reducer for key (react native)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I am trying to integrate redux navigation to my existing app. It shows me the error `No reducer provided for key navReducer`. Any help is appreciated. Other stackoverflow answers point to the fact that there is problem in importing when this kind of error occurs but I am not sure why this is occuring in my case.

My /components/navigation.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import Login from '../containers/loginContainer'
import Home from '../containers/homeContainer'
import {
  reduxifyNavigator,
  createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware,
  createNavigationReducer,
} from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers'

export const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
    },
    Home: { 
      screen: Home,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login'
  }
)

export const navReducer = createNavigationReducer(RootStack)

export const navigationMiddleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
  "root",
  state => state.nav,
)

const appNavigator = reduxifyNavigator(RootStack, "root")
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  state: state.nav,
})

export const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(appNavigator)
```

My store configuration is:

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import { navigationMiddleware } from './components/navigation'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'myKey',
  storage,
}

const middlewares = [thunk, navigationMiddleware]

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  {},
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
  )

)
const persistedStore = persistStore(store)

export default store
```

My root reducer looks something like this:

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { navReducer } from '../components/navigation'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  navReducer, // It throws the error here!!
})

export default rootReducer
```

Comment: Its not a duplicate, i already did tried that answer but it does not work for me.

Comment: My reducer is already in the question. navReducer is the default reducer for navigation for react native. I don't have a custom one. Refer to this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html